# Why is there no reanimated Uchiha fighting in fourth shinobi war?

Tags: naruto

Why didn't Kabuto reanimate any person from Uchiha clan like Sasuke's parents and all other that Itachi killed or any Uchiha that has lived in Konoha? Did he not have any one's dna or whatever it takes to reanimate? Is there any mention about this in manga or anime? Thanks.

Comment: I think he said something about only using the ones he needed. It could have been that or Tobi didn't let him? I don't remember it being mentioned... Wait, I think he said something about him not being able to infiltrate the Leaf Village (where I suppose the Uchiha bodies would have been buried) to get some bodies, like the Hokage's. Don't take my word though.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru, indeed Tobi didn't let Kabuto use the Uchiha DNA in Tobi's possession – even though Kabuto wanted to. (Reference in my answer below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your notions are correct:

1. It is the dead person's DNA that is needed for the reanimation (alias [Edo Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation)).<sup>[1]</sup>
2. There is good reason to assume Kabuto did not reincarnate most of the Uchiha clan members, because he was unable to obtain their DNAs:

"Kabuto mentions his desire to reincarnate certain shinobi [including] Shisui Uchiha";<sup>[2]</sup> and his ally in the [Fourth Shinobi World War](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Shinobi_World_War), Tobi **(**­SPOILER:

> alias [Obito Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha),

**)**, was in possession of their DNA,<sup>[3]</sup> but – being forced by Kabuto into this alliance in the first place<sup>[4]</sup> – did not let him use it.<sup>[3]</sup>  Controlling more Uchiha shinobi could have made Kabuto too powerful with respect to the possibility of him turning against Tobi.

However, Kabuto *did* summon Itachi Uchiha, Madara Uchiha, as well as (only in the anime) Inabi Uchiha<sup>[5]</sup> and used them in his war efforts.<sup>[6]</sup>

As @AyaseEri points out, we can not exclude the possibility that Kabuto has managed to reincarnate the other Uchihas after all and it was just not shown.

But definitely also factor in @ElPsyKongroo's answer [below](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/why-is-there-no-reanimated-uchiha-fighting-in-fourth-shinobi-war#answer-38197)  on why that's very unlikely!

---

**References**

[1]

> Before this technique can be performed, the user must first acquire some of the DNA of the person they intend to reincarnate.

—http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Usage

[2]
—http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation#cite_ref-Fivetwenty_1-5

[3]

> Kabuto could not find [Shisui Uchiha's] body. He suggested that one of Shisui's eyes that was crushed by Danzō Shimura, whose corpse was in Tobi's possession, would be sufficient. […] Tobi threatened him not to push his luck.

—http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation#cite_ref-Fivetwenty_1-5

[4]

> Kabuto [uses] the Impure World Reincarnation to revive five deceased Akatsuki members, which he offers to use to help Tobi in the approaching war. […] When Tobi contemplates refusing, Kabuto summons the real Madara Uchiha, forcing Tobi to agree.

—http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kabuto_Yakushi#Fourth_Shinobi_World_War:_Countdown

[5]
—http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Kabuto_Yakushi

[6]
—http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Shinobi_World_War
Search the page for the (indeed numerous) occurrences of "Uchiha".

Comment: This, or he did re-animate them. It just wasn't shown in the story. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @AyaseEri, you are absolutely right! I had handwavily extrapolated a bit from the reference to present a clearer answer. But that is not principled scholarship! :D I have now amended my post to diffentiate between interpretation and fact (as far as the reference goes) and I added your note to the answer. どうもすみません、ありがとうございます for your remark and your upboat!^.^

Comment: +1, it's a good answer and it looks like you actually took your time to research (and for the references).

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru, doumo arigatou! :) By the way, I think your [profile pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcQ25.jpg?s=328&g=1) looks marvelous!  I'm sure you make a great mangaka/ illustrator/ artist! :)

Comment: Most Uchiha were treated as Fodder anyway. Itachi and Tobi killed all of them (except Itachis Father) with ease. Considering the number of them, there could not have been more than a couple of regular jonin, and regular jonin are overall not that strong. Shisui and Itachi were the top 2 in the clan, and probably at least 50% of the ones worth reviving.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the exceptional answer given by accolade, I think there might be another reason. Note that after the Uchiha clan was slaughtered, most of the cleaning up was done by the Anbu under Danzo. And given how careful he is, I'm sure he would have made sure that the bodies are not discoverable, and so, Kabuto could not have been able to obtain any DNA.

Comment: Thank you for your friendly compliment^.^*blushes* and your valuable complement! ;) +1   I put a pointer to your answer into mine!

Comment: +1, although it doesn't seem like you researched for any of this and just assumed, it's still likely this happened. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Not a good strategy

Even if he could get their DNA they could probably know the edo tensei reversal jutsu or have some trick to defeat it like Itachi, and then rebel against him.

Comment: Itachi was able to get out of Kabuto's control because of Kotoamatsukami jutsu done by Shisui's eye implanted in the crow. I think an Uchiha army, whether they have Mangekyou Sharingan or not, would be a very good strategy for Kabuto.

Comment: @Bhaskar I'm sure that even if only one of them got out of the control of kabuto they could just release everyone else. Ofc kabuto could always spend more time and energy on them to try and keep them under absolute control.

Comment: Only Shisui's genjutsu can release the reanimated person out of Kabuto's control. No other Uchiha has a strong enough genjutsu to do the same. Sasuke's genjutsu after getting Indra's chakra might also be able to do it.

Comment: `Conversely, if the reincarnated soul knows the hand seals, they can sever the summoner's contract with them`. All it needs is one uchiha knowing the hand seals, breaking free, and teaching others the hand seals. Although I don't think they can be released after that, so they will have to live forever.

Comment: If thats the case, it doesnt have be an Uchiha. Anyone could break free if the reanimated person knows the hand seals. However Uchihas would have an advantage in that they could use Izanami on Kabuto and learn the hand seals themselves while sacrifing an eye. But they have to find Kabuto's location first. Itachi could only do that because Nagato told him. And before finding Kabuto's location, the person should break free of his control. Itachi was lucky to have Shisui's genjutsu, so what you are saying could only happen if Madara tells them the hand seals.

Comment: @Bhaskar The thing is that the technique was developed by the senju clan, and the uchiha clan was always at war with them, so I'm sure that some uchiha knew the technique just in case.

Answer (score -1):

Although the uchiha were hailed for there eyes, most wouldn't hold water to a slighty above average jounen. Besides that, there was only a few uchiha who were actually powerful, remember how they said the mangekyou sharingan was only awakened by 1 or 2 people? There not wrong, less than ten actually have them.